# dynamic form add/remove field

Tags: php, jquery, forms, dynamic

I try to create a form that can add/remove inputs dynamically.
I can create a new row by clicking a button, but when I pass a value to an other page my input seem to not be collected.

This is the code

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){
            //var               
            var x = 1;

            //add
            $("#add").click(function(e){
                x++;
                var mark = '<tr><td width="200" height="30" align="center">'+x+'</td><td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_name[]" /></td><td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_fact[]" /></td><td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_desc[]" /></td><td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_amount[]"/></td><td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_price[]" /></td><td width="200" height="30" align="center"><a herf="#" id="remove" class="button">X</a></td></tr>';
                $("#dynamic_field").append(mark);
            });
            //remove
            $("#dynamic_field").on('click','#remove', function(e){
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                x--;
            });
        });
    </script>
```

This is the html code

```
<tr id="container">
    <td width="200" height="30" align="center">1</td>
    <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_name[]"/></td>
    <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_fact[]"/></td>
    <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_desc[]"/></td>
    <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_amount[]"/></td>
    <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_price[]"/></td>
    <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><a herf="#" id="add" class="button">Add more</a></td>
</tr>
```

When `print_r` value it pass input just html input.

```
item_name => Array ( [0] =>test 1)
```

Comment: How do you pass the value to the other page?

Comment: I'm assuming you're doing an ajax call to pass the value to "the other page". You're going to have to add the code for the ajax too.

Comment: i'm passing value by post method by sumbit form. I need to code to pass value from ajax? I thought just append same input name going to do it. Any sample i can look?

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(e){

            var x = 1; //for row count

            //add more button click 
            $("#add").click(function(e){
                 x++;
```

//row html which is add on add more click
                  var mark = ''+x+'X';

```
             $("#mt tr:last").after(mark); //add the row after the last existing tr 

            });
            //code for X click
            $("#mt").on('click','#remove', function(e){
               //remove the current row
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                x--;
            });




        });
    </script>


 <table id="mt">
 <tr id="container">

                <td width="200" height="30" align="center">1</td>
                <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_name[]"/></td>
                <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_fact[]"/></td>
                <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_desc[]"/></td>
                <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_amount[]"/></td>
                <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><input type="text" name="item_price[]"/></td>
                <td width="200" height="30" align="center"><a href="javascript:void(0)" id="add" class="button">Add more</a></td>

    </tr>

</table>
```

Comment: when user click on  add more buttton  
$("#mt tr:last").after(mark); 
means  add a row after the last existing table row(tr). 

 $("#mt").on('click','#remove', function(e){
                $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                x--;
            });
remove the current row clicked  .

Comment: if any query please let me know  .

Comment: Please add such explanation to the code, not to the comment section